# Anchor tag stopped working after page reload

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table by default sorts by column 1.  When user sorts column 2 column 1 is out of order.  So far so good. Next I have 5 links (outside the table) that anchor to 5 spots inside the table (column 1).  When the table reloads to it's default column 1, the anchors stop working.

```
<a href="#s" onclick="window.location.reload()">Signature</a>
```

After pager reload, the anchor appears to go either the top or bottom of table.  I want the table to resort by column 1 and still hit the anchor spots.

Comment: We cannot debug code we cannot see.

Comment: Also no obvious reason to reload the page. Sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: @TheHeadRush Just close your eyes and clear your mind. The code will come to you.